# How do I determine if a required module came from a gem, or was a core module?

Tags: ruby

If I see a `require` in source code.

```
require "blah"
```

How do I determine if that library ("blah") was provided by the core ruby installation or if it came from the installation of a gem?

Comment: Absolutely nothing in Ruby Core requires `require`-ing. Perhaps you mean the [Standard Library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the `$LOADED_FEATURES` and check if path came from gem or not, which means that you are testing if the feature belongs to the core installation or not.

```
# return true if library is an external gem
$LOADED_FEATURES.grep(/library/).grep(/gems/).size > 0
```

Comment: I guess this works. I tested it out too. But I'm disappointed its not in metadata somewhere, and instead I'm greping for a keyword in a filesystem path. Oh well.

Answer (score 1):

Once `require` has found an loaded a library file it adds the full path to that file to the `$LOADED_FEATURES` array. So you could look in that array to see where it found `blah`

```
$LOADED_FEATURES.find_all { |path| puts path if /blah/ =~ path }
```

Comment: `$LOADED_FEATURES.select {|path| path.include?('WHAT TO FIND') }` works well for this, it returns an array, and you can use that how you wish.